# anonymous functions

Tags: z3

I have found the support for anonymous functions (lambda expressions) in Yices to be extremely helpful.  I am now trying to use Z3 to implement a tool, but I have not been able to figure out if this feature is supported.  I am invoking the tool using the -smt2 flag.  thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, lambda expressions are neither supported by Z3 (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365030/491216) by Nikolaj Bjorner, one of the main Z3 developers), nor are they part of the SMTLib2 standard. Solvers that support lambda expressions, for example, Yices or veriT, support them as a custom extension to the SMTLib2 standard.

Depending on your needs (which you might want to illustrate by adding an example to your questions) you could try Z3 macros (`define-fun`), or a front-end like [Z3Py](http://rise4fun.com/z3py) that, compared with writing SMTLib code manually, simplifies working with Z3 a lot.